# Install a different OS on my raspberry pi other than raspbian

Tags: raspberry-pi, iso

I would like to try other systems other than raspbian.

So, I have a debian.iso which i mounted by:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/iso
sudo mount -o loop /home/tim/Downloads/debian.iso /mnt/iso
```

okay, so now what is the next step to get it going?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to mount the iso. You need to "copy" the iso on your SD card.

See this page for instructions on how to copy an iso image to an SD card:
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/

By the way. You need to do this on another computer than the raspberry pi...

Answer (score 0):

Mounting is a very different thing to installing an OS. You mount something to an already loaded OS. If you want to install another OS, then you want to load it on its own. Therefore, it needs to have its place on the bootup medium like the SD card. Also, it needs to be bootable. So it needs to be included in the Grub list.

To try another system on your Pi the easiest way is to use a separate card for a separate OS. For this use Tobias' link. Putting two systems on one card is more complex.